# HTML Decrations are not working in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I am using Liferay 6 with Struts2 .
I have this Struts2 Tags JSP in Liferay .

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Login using Ravi</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
        <body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
          <s:form action="helloForm" method="POST" theme="simple">
          <table>
                    <tr>
    <td>Enter Your Name:<s:textfield name="namer" value="%{name}" required="true"/></tr>td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
                     <td>Enter Your Password:<s:textfield name="passer" value="%{passer}" /></tr>td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
    <s:submit/>
     <s:submit/>
      <s:submit/>
   </s:form>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

This page is being displayed , but the issue is that , the body color is not being chnaged at all .
And also when i tried to set the body height width and all they are not being reflected .

Or is it that   using themes only we can achieve this ?

Comment: can u please clarify a little as to what exactly are you trying to do here. I mean does this JSP go inside a plugin-portlet or have u modified some liferay JSP with a hook or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Liferay cut the html-, header- and body-tag out. After the cutting remain all inside body tag:

```
<s:form action="helloForm" method="POST" theme="simple">
          <table>
                    <tr>
    <td>Enter Your Name:<s:textfield name="namer" value="%{name}" required="true"/></tr>td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
                     <td>Enter Your Password:<s:textfield name="passer" value="%{passer}" /></tr>td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
    <s:submit/>
     <s:submit/>
      <s:submit/>
   </s:form>
```

but you can modify look-and-feel from portlet with portlet specific css.
Set in liferay-portlet.xml `<css-class-wrapper>your-portlet-name-or-some-thing-uniq</css-class-wrapper>`

and add in /MyPortlet/docroot/css/main.css

```
.your-portlet-name-or-some-thing-uniq {
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
}
```